# Auto assigned nodeId for azure spring app or how to get app instance name

Tags: spring-boot, azure-spring-cloud, azure-spring-boot

In azure spring boot app while having multiple instances I need to get somehow its app instance name, or would be perfect to configure nodeId generation ( int/long type , but if now I can live with name ).
Anyone knows how to access this data from code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get app instances name list from application code, you may try to use the following REST API:

1. To list all the instances names in an app, we can use

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.AppPlatform/Spring/{serviceName}/apps/{appName}/deployments?api-version=2022-12-01
```

You should be able to find all the instances name in the response json file.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "properties": {
        ...,
        "instances": [
          {
            "name": "<app name>-<deployment name>-x-xxxxxxxx-xxxx",
            "status": "Running",
            "discoveryStatus": "UP",
            "startTime": "2023-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ"
          },
          ...
        ],
```

Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azurespringapps/deployments/list?tabs=HTTP

2. To list all the instances names in the Azure Spring Apps service:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.AppPlatform/Spring/{serviceName}/deployments?api-version=2022-12-01
```

You can find the instance list in the 'properies' -> 'instances' of the request response.

Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azurespringapps/deployments/list-for-cluster?tabs=HTTP

3. You can also use Azure Resource Manager App Platform client library for Java SDK to access the information in your code.

Reference doc: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/resourcemanager/azure-resourcemanager-appplatform

Comment: thanks but its listing all not current one

Comment: For the current app instance name, we can read from the environment variable HOSTNAME.  

It should look like this:    
HOSTNAME=<app name>-<deployment name>-x-xxxxxxxx-xxxx